# Global list shows empty in python

Tags: python, django, global-variables

I have declared a global list `feature_array` like this and then initialized it in the `get_features(request)` function:

```
feature_array = []


def get_features(request):

    selected_product_id = request.session['product_id']

    all_features = Feature.objects.filter(product_id = selected_product_id)

    global feature_array
    feature_array = list(all_features)
```

Now I want to delete the first index of the list in another function but `IndexError: list assignment index out of range` comes up although I have initialized it in the `get_features` function. Following is how I delete the list's first index. I suppose it gets an empty list that's why it couldn't access the first index.

```
def process_features_ajax(request):
    global feature_array
    del feature_array[0]
```

**UPDATE**

This is how I call the `get_features(request)` function

```
(customer_comments, request) = get_features(request)
```

Comment: How are you running your Django server? How is `get_features()` called? Is `process_features_ajax` located in the same module or did you import `feature_array` into a second module?

Comment: Actually when I run my Django server locally everything works fine. but when I run it on the AWS ec2 instance it gives me that error.

Yes process_features_ajax and feature_array are in the same views.py and the same module

Answer (score 0):

You cannot rely on globals being shared if you are running in a *forking model* WSGI environment.

To handle requests, a forking model server will create new child processes. These inherit the parent process memory and after forking, globals are no longer shared between requests. Don't rely on globals and use a database or memory cache process (memcached or redis) instead.

Comment: What could be the alternate for this? I NEED feature_array to persist the change once I delete its first index

Comment: @user3537880: the alternative is to use only threading, but I don't know what WSGI container you are using, nor is your code likely to be tread safe. Better to stick with a database or memory cache.

Answer (score 0):

As Martijn says, you must absolutely not use global variables for storing state between requests in a multi-process environment. Apart from the issues you have already seen, there is also the additional problem of multiple users: obviously, with global variables, everyone would have access to the same value, which can't be right.

The way to do something like this in Django is to use the session. You're already using it from the product ID: you should store the IDs of the features you want in there as well, and modify that list as necessary.

Comment: Yes, originally I was also using session to store all the features for a particular product. Can I delete the first entry somehow from the session variable like in the list, I'm having difficulties in that

Comment: I have done this
    'js_features = json.loads(serializers.serialize("json", all_features))
    request.session['features'] = js_features'

Now how can I delete the any feature's first index somehow